# JMenu disappears when JRadioButtons or JCheckBoxes are used

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, jradiobutton, jmenubar

I have created a JMenuBar with a Pizza JMenu. The JMenu has 3 JRadioButtons and 2 JCheckBoxes that appear when menuItems are scrolled over. The problem is that when I click on a JRadioButton or JCheckBox, the whole menu disappears. Is there a particular method or any other way I can stop this from happening?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MenuExamplePizza extends JFrame
{
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu, sizeMenu, extrasMenu, helpMenu;
    private JMenuItem menuItem;private JRadioButtonMenuItem smallrbMenuItem, medrbMenuItem, largerbMenuItem;
    private JCheckBoxMenuItem peppchMenuItem, anchMenuItem;

public MenuExamplePizza()                                                               // Default Constructor
{
   menuBar = new JMenuBar();                                                                        //Create the menu bar

    menu = new JMenu("Pizza");                                                                      //Build the first menu
    menu.setMnemonic('P');
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("The only menu in this program that has menu items");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Total");
    menuItem.setMnemonic('T');
    menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_T, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("This doesn't really do anything");
    menu.add(menuItem);
    menu.addSeparator();

    sizeMenu = new JMenu("Size");
    sizeMenu.setMnemonic('S');
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    smallrbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Small");
    group.add(smallrbMenuItem);
    sizeMenu.add(smallrbMenuItem);
    medrbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Medium");
    group.add(medrbMenuItem);
    sizeMenu.add(medrbMenuItem);
    largerbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Large");
    group.add(largerbMenuItem);
    sizeMenu.add(largerbMenuItem);
    menu.add(sizeMenu);

    extrasMenu = new JMenu("Extras");
    extrasMenu.setMnemonic('E');
    peppchMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Pepperoni");
    extrasMenu.add(peppchMenuItem);
    anchMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Anchovies");
    extrasMenu.add(anchMenuItem);
    menu.add(extrasMenu);

    menu.addSeparator();                                                                        // a group of radio button menu items                                                                       

    menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    menuItem.setMnemonic('x');
    menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("This doesn't really do anything");
    menu.add(menuItem);

    helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");                                                           //Build second menu in the menu bar.

    menuBar.add(menu);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);
    add(menuBar);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "whole menu disappear" ? is `Pizza` menu become invisible?

Comment: Yes the Pizza menu becomes invisible when I click on a menuItem, JCheckBox or JRadioButton.

Comment: But it is working fine at my side.

Comment: If you have registered any ActionListener to them then let me know that...

Comment: Is your complaint that the menu _closes_ on click? Or is the entire menu actually being removed from the menu bar?

Comment: Yes my complaint is that the menu closes on click, I want it to stay open so I can keep using the menu.

Comment: Whatever you are seeing is the inherent property of menu..after you click a menuitem it contracts to menu.. It is not an error or bug..

Comment: So it is impossible to change this?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Keeping Menus Open](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/keeping-menus-open/) to see if it does what you want.